# Расшифровка UML диагрмм последовательности

Tags: архитектура, uml

Разложите по полочкам, пожалуйста, что происходит на этих диаграммах? Может пример какой-то простой на псевдокоде?

[image: Диаграмма 1]

[image: Диаграмма 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Основные элементы диаграммы последовательности

#### Объекты

Объекты взаимодействующих классов на диаграмме изображаются прямоугольником с именем экземпляра внутри него.

#### Время (Линия жизни)

Особенностью диаграммы последовательности является явное отображение течения времени - имеется ось времени,  направленная (по умолчанию) сверху вниз. У каждого объекта имеется *линия жизни* - пунктирная вертикальная линия от прямоугольника до знака уничтожения объекта (крестик). Прямоугольники поверх линии жизни - отрезки времени, в течении которых объект владеет *потоком управления* (или проще говоря, объект активируется).

#### Сообщения и сигналы

Это способ общения объектов. Причем сообщение может:

1. Передавать управление объекту
2. Передавать сигналы (информировать)
3. Создавать объект

Над сообщениями указываются названия методов, которые они описывают.

---

Псевдокод для 2.1:

```
calculateRecognitions(contactID) //Вызов метода и активация объекта RecognitionService
{  ...
  RecognitionService.findContract(contractID) //Активация объекта DataGetAway 
  ...
  DataGetAway.newContractResultSet() //Создание объекта Contract Result Set
  ...
  RecognitionService.getData(ContractResultSet) //Передача управления объекту Contract Result Set
  ...
  RecognitionService.insert(DataGetAway) //Активация объекта DataGetAway 
  ...
}
```

Надеюсь, что помог вам.